# How to implement an upload form in .Net Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I create a **.Net Core API** ( I use **swagger** with it).

I create a controller in order to upload a picture to link it to an item.

**.cs** :

```
[HttpPut("[Action]/{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Link(int id, IFormFile file)
{
    var item = await _context.Item.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("item null");
    }

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        // code to link
        return Ok(file);
    }
}
```

My issue is if I want to test to know if it works, I have to use postman but I want to test it in my api.

A solution exist for my issue ? For the moment it look like that : 
[image: upload file]

Comment: What is your .net core version and swagger version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` with `4.0.1` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger` with `4.0.1`, it supports `IFormFile` with `swagger/index.html`.

Detail steps:

1. Install package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` with `4.0.1` and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger` with `4.0.1`
2. `Startup.cs`

   ```
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }

       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
           services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
           {
               c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
           });

       }

       // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
           }
           else
           {
               // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
               app.UseHsts();
           }

           app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
           app.UseSwagger();
           // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
           // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
           app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
           {
               c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
           });

           app.UseMvc();
       }
   }
   ```
3. `ApiController`

   ```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
   {
       [HttpPut("[Action]/{id}")]
       public async Task<ActionResult> Link(int id, IFormFile file)
       {
           return Ok(id);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`IFormFile` only works for `multipart/form-data` encoded requests. To send via JSON, you need to bind to `byte[]`, and then send the file data as either a Base64-encoded string or a uint array (i.e. the JSON equivalent of a `byte[]`.

Also, JSON is an *object notation* format, so you must bind to an object. For example:

```
public class MyFileUploadModel
{
    public byte[] File { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Link(int id, MyFileUploadModel model)
```

Finally, you'd send a JSON object like:

```
{
    "file": "[base64 encoded string here]"
}
```

OR

```
{
    "file": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Where `[1, 2, 3]` would actually be an array of the bytes in the file (i.e. numbers 0-255).